# Consequences of eigenvector-eigenvalue formula found by studying neutrinos

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis, matrix-theory

[This article](https://nonperele.com/three-physicists-stumbled-upon-a-striking-mathematical-discovery/) describes the discovery by three physicists, Stephen Parke of Fermi National Accelerator Laboratory, Xining Zhang of the University of Chicago, and Peter Denton of Brookhaven National Laboratory, of a striking relationship between the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of [Hermitian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix) matrices, found whilst studying neutrinos.

Their result has been written up in collaboration with Terence Tao [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.03795.pdf). From what I understand, although very similar results had been observed before, the link to eigenvector computation had not been explicitly made prior to now. For completeness here is the main result, "Lemma 2" from their paper:

> Let $A$ be a $n × n$ Hermitian matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_i(A)$ and normed eigenvectors $v_i$.
>   The elements of each eigenvector are denoted $v_{i,j}$. Let $M_j$ be the
>   $(n − 1) × (n − 1)$ submatrix of $A$ that results from deleting the $j^{\text{th}}$ column and the $j^{th}$ row, with eigenvalues $\lambda_k(M_j)$.
>
> **Lemma 2**. *The norm squared of the elements of the eigenvectors are related to the
>   eigenvalues and the submatrix eigenvalues,*
>   $$|v_{i,j}|^2\prod_{k=1;k\neq i}^n(\lambda_i(A)-\lambda_k(A))=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(\lambda_i(A)-\lambda_k(M_j))$$

**I was wondering what are the mathematical consequences of this beautiful result?**

For example are there any infinite dimensional generalisations? Does it affect matrix algorithms or proofs therein? What about [singular values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition)?

Comment: there is a very extensive discussion on Tao's [blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2019/08/13/eigenvectors-from-eigenvalues)

Comment: The [Quanta Magazine article](https://www.quantamagazine.org/neutrinos-lead-to-unexpected-discovery-in-basic-math-20191113/) of four days ago has also now been republished in [The Atlantic](https://www.theatlantic.com/science/archive/2019/11/neutrino-oscillations-lead-striking-mathematical-discovery/602128/).

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thanks for the heads up. There isn't much discussion of potential applications there - I guess we will have to wait and see.

Comment: "What about singular values?" - presumably, one could use this result on the matrix $$\mathbf G=\begin{pmatrix}&\mathbf B^\ast\\\mathbf B&\end{pmatrix}$$, since if $\mathbf B$ has singular values $\sigma_k$, then $\mathbf G$ has eigenvalues $\pm\sigma_k$.

Comment: Additionally, even if $\mathbf B$ is rectangular, $\mathbf G^\ast=\mathbf G$. (On another note, [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1137/S0036144504443110) might be of interest.)

Comment: Tiny correction, the eigenvalues of the cross product matrix are the *squares* of the singular values of the original. (This is the part of the reason why forming the cross-product matrix is often numerically unsound.) Applied to the result in the OP, the squaring is likely to complicate the formulae a fair bit.

Comment: The squares of the singular values of $M$ are the eigenvalues of $MM^*$ or $M^*M$, so this is another way to apply the result to compute singular values.

Comment: One trivial corollary is that, when summing over j, we have an identity relating all these n^2 real numbers. That is one equation for each i (assuming A has distinct eigenvalues). Q: Are these the only constraint, apart from Cauchy's interlacing? (n=2 case checks out.)

Comment: One consequence is: If the media reports that "a new and surprisingly simple equation has been found" it's very likely that the equation is not that new.

Comment: There is a new [post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2019/12/03/eigenvectors-from-eigenvalues-a-survey-of-a-basic-identity-in-linear-algebra/) by tao

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The OP asks about generalisations and applications of the formula in [arXiv:1908.03795](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.03795.pdf).

$\bullet$ *Concerning generalisations:* I have found an older paper, from 1993, where it seems that the same result as in the 2019 paper has been derived for [*normal* matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix) (with possibly complex eigenvalues) --- rather than just for Hermitian matrices: [On the eigenvalues of principal submatrices of normal, hermitian and symmetric matrices](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/03081089308818276?needAccess=true), by Peter Nylen, Tin-Yau Tam & Frank Uhlig (1993): theorem 2.2 (with the identification $b_{ij}=|u_{ij}|^2$ made at the very end of the proof).

A further generalisation to a *signed* inner product has been given in [On the eigenvalues of principal submatrices of J-normal matrices](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379511004435) (2011). In that case $b_{ij}=\epsilon_i\epsilon_j|u_{ij}|^2$, with $\epsilon_i=\pm 1$ the signature of the inner product: $(x,y)=\sum_i \epsilon_i x_i^\ast y_i$.

$\bullet$ *Concerning applications:* in the 1993 paper the theorem is used to solve the following problem: when does a normal $n\times n$ matrix $A$ with principal sub-matrices $M_j$ exist, given the sets of *distinct* (complex) eigenvalues $\lambda_i(A)$ of $A$ and $\lambda_k(M_j)$ of $M_j$. The answer is that the matrix $B$ with elements
$$b_{ij}=\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(\lambda_i(A)-\lambda_k(M_j))}{\prod_{k=1;k\neq i}^n(\lambda_i(A)-\lambda_k(A))}$$
should be [unistochastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unistochastic_matrix), meaning that $b_{ij}=|u_{ij}|^2$, where the matrix $U$ with elements $u_{ij}$ is the eigenvector matrix of $A$.

---

Since the 1993 paper is behind a paywall, I reproduce the relevant page:

[image]

<sub>A brief Mathematica file to test the formula is [here.](https://ilorentz.org/beenakker/MO/unistochastic.nb)</sub>

---

**Addendum:** following up on the trail pointed out by [Alan Edelman](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2019/08/13/eigenvectors-from-eigenvalues/#comment-529031) on Tao's blog: this [1966 paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1256055111) by R.C. Thompson, *"Principal submatrices of normal and Hermitian matrices"*, has the desired formula in the general case of normal matrices as Equation (15).

[image]

where $\theta_{ij}=|u_{ij}|^2$ when all eigenvalues $\mu_\alpha$ of $A$ are distinct (the $\xi_{ij}$'s are eigenvalues of $M_i$). The older papers mentioned in the comments below do not seem to have an explicit formula for $|u_{ij}|^2$.

Because this appears to be the earliest appearance of the eigenvector/eigenvalue identity, it might be appropriate to refer to it as *"Thompson's identity",$^*$* as a tribute to professor [Robert Thompson](http://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Thompson_Robert.html) (1931-1995). It would fit in nicely with this quote from the [obituary:](http://texts.cdlib.org/view?docId=hb0z09n6nn;NAAN=13030&doc.view=frames&chunk.id=div00064&toc.depth=1&toc.id=&brand=calisphere)

> Among Thompson's many services to research was his help in dispelling
>   the misinformed view that linear algebra is simple and uninteresting.
>   He often worked on difficult problems, and as much as anyone, he
>   showed that core matrix theory is laden with deeply challenging and
>   intellectually compelling problems that are fundamentally connected to
>   many parts of mathematics.

<sub>$^*$ "Thompson's identity" to distinguish from [Thompson's formula](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/218279/finding-u-v-in-thompsons-formula)</sub>

Comment: Thanks Carlo this is excellent!

Comment: note this thread:https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/eigenvectors-from-eigenvalues-terence-tao-et-al-beyond-andrew-knyazev/ where the author gives reference as back as 1930!

Comment: thanks @PiyushGrover; I tried to follow up on the links you mention; Eq. (2.2.26) in the [1986 paper](http://math.ucdenver.edu/~aknyazev/research/papers/old/k.pdf) is a formula for the overlap squared of the eigenvectors of $A$ and $M_i$; Eq. (2.29) in the [1960 paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/dd58/71b7a8e6c07071bc04e483c09841919f80e3.pdf) gives the overlap squared between an eigenvector and its Rayleigh-Ritz approximation; presumably the 1993 formula for $|u_{ij}|^2$ can be easily obtained from these earlier results, but $|u_{ij}|^2$ is not explicitly given, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I also looked up the [1934 paper](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PID=GDZPPN002374994) mentioned in @PiyushGrover 's link:  _"Über monotone Matrixfunktionen"_ by Karl Löwner. It is a long (40-page) paper, but I could not locate any equation that would identify $|u_{ij}|^2$ --- did I overlook something?

Comment: Formula 8 in Löwner's paper looks awfully like the currently popular result.

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician -- the left-hand-side of Eq. 8 of Löwner is again an overlap of eigenvectors of two different matrices, rather than the absolute value squared $|u_{ij}|^2$ of the eigenvector of a single matrix. (I am not implying one cannot obtain a result for $|u_{ij}|^2$ from such an overlap, but as far as I can tell, the 1993 paper is the earliest where that particular quantity is expressed in terms of eigenvalues.)

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I think the 1993 paper is particularly interesting and relevant as not only does it contain the formula precisely it also proves a sort of converse to the normal matrix generalisation of the recent result - a given set of matrix and sub-matrix eigenvalues are from a normal matrix iff the formula gives values that are derived from a unitary matrix by taking the norm square of the elements.

Answer (score 13):

I want to add to the list of places where this identity has been used previously.

For a recent one, see [arXiv:1710.02181](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.02181) “State transfer in strongly regular graphs with an edge perturbation”. 
Equation (2) in Section 2 of this reads
\[
    \frac{\phi(X\setminus a,t)}{\phi(X,t)} = \sum_r \frac{(E_r)_{a,a}}{t-\theta_r}
\]
If the eigenvalue $\theta_r$ is simple. $E_r=z_rz_r^T$ and we have formula (2.3) in the pdf
given in Carlos's reply.
I have used it in a number of places in work on continuous quantum walks, e.g - Lemma 7.1 and Corollary 7.2 in arXiv:1011.0231 "When can perfect state transfer occur?"

It is used implicitly in my paper with Brendan McKay: "[Spectral conditions for the reconstructibility of a graph](https://doi.org/10.1016/0095-8956(81)90046-0)", JCT B (30), 1981, 285–289.

We missed the connection to neutrinos :-(

There is an extensive treatment in Chapter 4 of my book "Algebraic Combinatorics". Chapman & Hall, New York, 1993.

Related identities appear in C. A. Coulson and H. C. Longuet-Higgins: "The electronic structure of conjugated systems I. General theory", Proc. Roy. Soc. London A191 (1947), 39–60. They prove that
if $G$ is a graph with adjacency matrix $A$ and characteristic polynomial $\phi(G,t)$ and $\phi_{ij}(G)$ is the $ij$-entry of $\phi(G,t)(tI-A)^{-1}$, then
\[
    \phi_{ij}(G,t) = \sum_P \phi(G\setminus P,t)
\]
(where the sum is over all paths $P$ in $G$ from $i$ to $j$, and $G\setminus P$ is $G$ with all vertices in $P$ deleted). Further
\[
    \phi_{ij}(G,t) = \sqrt{\phi(G\setminus i,t)\phi(G\setminus j,t)-\phi(G,t)\phi(G\setminus {i,j},t)}.
\]

The connection with eigenvectors arises because if $A=\sum_r \theta_r E_r$ is the spectral decomposition of $A$, then
\[
    \frac{\phi_{ij}(G,\theta_r)}{\phi'(G,\theta_r)} = (E_r)_{i,j}.
\]

Essentially, the identity relates diagonal entries of spectral idempotents of Hermitian matrices to characteristic polynomials of principal submatrices. The off-diagonal entries are related to Green's functions, and I expect that there are papers in the physics literature
where versions of the identity appear.

Comment: There is nothing new under the sun.

Comment: it might be helpful if you could perhaps include some of these identities in your answer; I checked the 1947 paper and have difficulty locating it, and I'm also unsure how to extract it from the more recent papers you mention.

Comment: I would like to second Carlo's request.  I have also just searched through all the references you mention and was unable to locate identities close to the one discussed here.  The identity $\frac{\phi_{ij}(G,\theta_r)}{\phi'(G,\theta_r)} = (E_r)_{i,j}$ you mention is somewhat close to our identity, but I wasn't able to locate it in any of the references you gave.

Comment: I hope I have come closer to satisfying Carlo's request now.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil Thanks for your comprehensive research on this subject Chris, very much appreciated. In the interests of keeping things on topic I just wanted to to steer things towards my specific question which was really about the mathematical consequences of this result rather than previous possible occurrences of related results in the literature. For example can you describe in a way that's accessible to as wide an audience as possible, the application you allude to in your paper with Brendan McKay. Thanks!